# Contact Form Sending blank Data in PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I have recently made a website for my friend and contains a contact form using PHP. When the person sends the email, the data is not sent through the email.

This is the code for the website

```
<article class="grid_8">
    <div class="indent-left">
        <h3 class="p1">Contact us</h3>
        <form id="contact-form" method="post" name="myemailform" action="contact_form.php">  
            <fieldset>
                <label><span class="text-form">Name:</span><input name="name" type="text" required /></label>
                <label><span class="text-form">Email:</span><input name="email" type="text" required /></label>                              
                <label><span class="text-form">Phone:</span><input name="phone" type="text" /></label>                              
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="text-form">Message:</div>
                    <div class="extra-wrap">
                        <textarea name="message" required></textarea>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <div class="buttons">
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button">
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </div>                            
            </fieldset>                     
        </form>
    </div>
</article>
```

This is the code for the PHP

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email_from = $_POST['email'];
$email_subject = $_POST["New Message From www.chevroncreativesolutions.com"];
$email_body = $_POST["You have received a new message from $name.\n".
                     "Here is the message:\n $message.\n You Can call me on $phone.\n"].

$to = "matthias.mccarthy@gmail.com";
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$contact_form=mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

if($contact_form) {
    echo "Message has been sent.";
    echo "<form><input type='button' value='Return back' onclick='history.back();'></form>";
} else {
    echo "Error In sending your message";
    echo "<form><input type='button' value='Return back' onclick='history.back();'></form>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are setting your `$email_subject` and `$email_body` values to undefined `$_POST` values:

```
$email_subject = $_POST["New Message From www.chevroncreativesolutions.com"];
$email_body = $_POST["You have received a new message from $name.\n".
                     "Here is the message:\n $message.\n You Can call me on $phone.\n"];
```

Instead, drop the `$_POST[]` part:

```
$email_subject = "New Message From www.chevroncreativesolutions.com";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from $name.\n".
              "Here is the message:\n $message.\n You Can call me on $phone.\n";
```

Additionally, but unrelated to your issue, you'll want to sanitize the `$email_from` field to prevent header injection:

```
$email_from = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
if ($email_from === false) {
    echo 'error, invalid email';
}
```

Comment: Worked Perfectly, I have trying to solve this issue for some time now thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your `$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";` must be `"From: $EmailFrom" . "\r\n"`.

You are missing a `.`